# why do i get two user ids when creating a user in firebase using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i sign up a user in my ios app it generates a user id and adds that to the data base with the users name and surname and username but it is generating a user id and another random number/id and i dont know what that is for:

[image]

i dont know what the Roy... is and dont know where its coming from.
so when i try and access the users uid to access the information such as the name and surname i keep getting the following error because its using the wc7... number and not the other one:

Listener at /Users/wc7VyejKlDNfcAhFu3AkIX9Y9on1/Username failed: permission_denied

this is my code that i use to try and access the users information:

```
func fetchUsersData() {

    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    print("Current user id is \(currentUser)")


    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(currentUser).child(USER_NAME).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {return}
        self.navigationItem.title = username
    }
}
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: "Roy..." is your "documentId". which is randomly crated by firebase if you don't pass any value to it.

Comment: so how would i access the information like firstname?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code of: 1) how you write this document, 2) how you then try to read it. Without seeing this code, it'll be hard to help. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The biggest issue is your code is for the Firebase Real Time Database and the screen shot is for Firestore. They are totally different and unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

That code is for the Firebase Real Time Database and the screen shot is for Cloud Firestore. They are totally different and unrelated.

If you want to read the data shown in your screenshot you need to use the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) documentation.

The documentID 'Roy...' happens when you don't assign a document an ID... it will generate one automatically.

Also, change your Firestore structure to use the users uid as the documentID. So it would look like this

```
users //the collection
   uid_0 //the document with documentID = a users uid
      first_name: "Hank"
      last_name: "Jones"
      user_name: "Hankster"
   uid_1
      first_name: "Leroy"
      last_name: "Jenkins"
      user_name: "Leeeerrroooyyy"
```

and then the code to read a specific user name based on a uid is this

```
func readUserName() {
    let users = self.db.collection("users")
    let thisUser = users.document(the users uid)
    thisUser.getDocument(completion: { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let snap = documentSnapshot else { return }
        let docId = snap.documentID
        let userName = snap.get("user_name") as? String ?? "No Name"
        print(userName)
    })
}
```

Also note that you will need to be authenticated to Firestore to read any data *or* adjust the Security Rules to allow anyone to read. That's not generally a good idea but when you're just getting started it's ok.